# Output on a single line

Tags: unix, sed, awk

The following code is working as expected. But I can not format the output.
It will print something like this:

```
mysql
test
someDB
```

I want the output on a single line

```
mysql test someDB
```

I tried using sed in the script but it did not work.

```
#!/bin/sh
for dbName in `mysqlshow -uroot -pPassWord | awk '{print $2}'`
do
echo "$dbName" | egrep -v 'Databases|information_schema';
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do a variation combining **naumcho**'s and **rsp**'s answers that will work for small numbers of results:

```
echo $(mysqlshow -uroot -pPassWord | awk '{print $2}' | egrep -v 'Databases|information_schema')
```

Answer (score 12):

whenever you want to combine all lines of output into one you can also use xargs:

e.g.

```
find 
.
./zxcv
./fdsa
./treww
./asdf
./ewr
```

becomes:

```
find |xargs echo
. ./zxcv ./fdsa ./treww ./asdf ./ewr
```

Answer (score 6):

you can use tr to get your output to one line

```
<output from somewhere> | tr "\n" " "
```

Answer (score 1):

The newline is generated by the echo command most likely, the following should do the same without the newlines (not tested)

```
mysqlshow -uroot -pPassWord | awk '{print $2}' | egrep -v 'Databases|information_schema'
```

and has the added bonus of spawning just 1 grep instead of 3 grep processes.

Comment: Isn't awk printing newlines, too?

Comment: even better...just one awk command:  mysqlshow -uroot -pPassWord| awk '!/Databases|information_schema/{print $2}'